# Can an external backup drive became uninitialized on its own?

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive, toshiba-hard-drive

I have a brand new Toshiba 3Tb external that I used once to store by back-ups while I gave my computer a clean state, (after a couple years she was starting to lag.) After backing up, I tested the drive and information on it before formatting my laptop and loosing my only other copy of my files.

When I went to put my files back on Windows said the drive is not initialized, when I go to do so, it will not allow any kind of initialization, even with under a terabyte of information on it. I've tried to initialize the drive on multiple systems and 3 different types of Windows (7 Professional, Vista, and XP) and nothing. Now I'm stuck with a clean laptop without any access to the files on the drive.

Is it possible for a drive to just become uninitialized on its own? If yes or no, is there any way to retrieve the files still on the drive?

Comment: Why are you trying so hard to reinitialise the drive if it contains your important data? If Windows fails to read the drive for some reason, you can see if your data is accessible via Linux. If not, there might be a hardware issue with the drive, the cable, the enclosure/case...

Comment: Not a bad idea with the Linux, I've got an old laptop collecting dust somewhere around here. Thanks for the advice, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: In case the old laptop doesn't work, any Linux LiveCD/USB will do just as well.

Comment: Linux got my information off, was a fault with the drive. I'll return it and stay away from the cheap Toshiba drives this time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Clee - glad to hear you solved your problem. @Karan - Would you care to add that as an answer?

Comment: @Karan - I've added it as a Community Wiki answer for the time being. If you want to add your own answer, do so and ping me, and I'll remove the CW answer :)

Comment: @Robotnik: Very late response from me but that's all right, thanks for adding it as a CW answer. :) The OP hasn't been back anyway.

Comment: @Karan - no problem. I figured it's better to have it answered for future visitors - if it gets an upvote it will count as 'answered' and will stop auto-bumping to the front page as well

Answer (score 0):

From Karan's comments:

Why are you trying so hard to reinitialise the drive if it contains your important data? If Windows fails to read the drive for some reason, you can see if your data is accessible via Linux.

(Any Linux LiveCD/USB will do, In case your old laptop doesn't work).

If not, there might be a hardware issue with the drive, the cable or the enclosure/case.